# iptables change destination address base on result from mysql

Tags: mysql, iptables, nat

I need to change destination address of tcp/ip packets based on result of execution mysql query...

SELECT `score` FROM `reputation` WHERE `ip` = packet.source_ip

if (score < a) then packet.destination_ip = ...

else packet.destination_ip = ...

What ways of solving this problem do you see?
Thanks.

P.S. this is important that destination host knows REAL ip address where packet came from, not IP address of firewall.

Comment: Try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How often do the scores change?  If not often, you can export the info you need into iptables.  In a quick search, I don't see a way for iptables to read directly from the database, so you might be SOL.

Comment: I thought about exporting, but scores will change quite frequently... There are way to go one plugin for mysql that allow execute shell commands in triggers, i'm thinking about it.